# Observable variables don't work on reload

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, observable

I'm working on an existing application where Knockout 2.1.0 with JQuery 1.7.0 is used.

Scenario: I have 3 observable variables for and Item (Id, Name, version). On click of the Add button I clear the observables and accept new values from the UI. E.g.

```
myObservableId("");
```

On click on Edit from List view, I set observable values from List Row. E.g.

```
myObservableId(1234);
```

On Save, I check for Id field:

```
if id == null
    createNewItem()
else
   editItem(id)
```

See [this sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpXjL/).

This works fine when the page is loaded the first time (or I refresh the browser F5/ctrl+r), but the issue is that this is a single page application (index.html) and multiple templates are used.

When I navigate to other template and return. It stops working. Observable variables doesn't hold data which I update using code.

I've tried debugging it. When in Edit Code, it shows that observable variable's value is changed, but in `save()` values are blank. So it always goes to `CreateItem()`.

Is it due to `ko.applyBindings(...)`? Every time the template is revisited it reapplies all functions and bindings.

Comment: I'm not sure you're showing enough code here. Do you use an observableArray somewhere? As you seem to want to update an item if it exists, otherwise you create a new item, so I assume you have an array of items somewhere?

Comment: No, I didn't have any observable array.

But I found the issue. It was due to multiple bindings.
On every reload ModelView was recreated and bindings were re applied. 

So I prevented it by adding the ModelViews in a JS Map and using the same everytime.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to multiple bindings. On every reload ModelView was recreated and bindings were re applied. So I prevented it by adding the ModelViews in a JS Map and using the same everytime. Thanks for the response.